# bmi calculator how do restart the calculator to go back to yes/no at the top

Tags: python, function, input

```
Take_Bmi=(input("Take bmi yes or no "))

if Take_Bmi == "yes":
    name1=input(" enter your name")
    height_m1=input(" enter your height in m")
    weight_kg1=input(" enter your weight")
    def bmi_calculator(name1,height_m1,weight_kg1):
        bmi = float(weight_kg1) / (float(height_m1)** 2)
```

#The input function returns a string. So to get your output you 
  #need to use "float()" for height and weight:
            print("bmi: ")

```
        if bmi < 25 :

            print(bmi)
            return name1 + " not overweight"
        else:
            print(bmi)

            return name1 + " is overweight"

   result= bmi_calculator(name1,float(height_m1),float(weight_kg1))
   print(result)

else:
    print("thank you")
```

## how do i like repeat this test like print(do you wan to take again)

## goes back to would you like to take bmu yes /no at the top

Comment: The indentation doesn't look right.

Comment: in addition to your indentation, `input` always returns a string. you should convert its result to a float where necessary.

Comment: Why do you think the input "isn't going to" the function? What happened when you tried the code, and how is that different from what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function returns a string.
So to get your output you need to use "float()" for height and weight:

```
bmi = float(weight_kg1) / (float(height_m1)** 2)
```

Also, you have to *call* your function, e.g.

```
bmi_calculator(name1,float(height_m1),float(weight_kg1))
```

Comment: Pretty sure `int` wouldn't be a good type, certainly for height in meters. Likely `float` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

After printing the result
You can add a if else condition where you can take input from the user and ask them, then accordingly you can recall your function or else exit it.

Like this:-

```
Take_Bmi=(input("Take bmi yes or no "))

if Take_Bmi == "yes":

def takeBMI():

    name1=input(" enter your name")

    height_m1=input(" enter your height in m")

    weight_kg1=input(" enter your weight")

    def bmi_calculator(name1,height_m1,weight_kg1):

        bmi = float(weight_kg1) / (float(height_m1)** 2)

        if bmi < 25 :


            print(bmi)

            return name1 + " not overweight"

        else:

            print(bmi)


            return name1 + " is overweight"


    result= bmi_calculator(name1,float(height_m1),float(weight_kg1))

    print(result)

    again=(input("Take bmi again yes or no "))

    if again=="yes":

        takeBMI()

    else:

        exit(0)

takeBMI()

else:

print("thank you")
```